# Jmeter- Under response data it is displaying error but under sampler result it is displaying 'Response message: OK'

Tags: jmeter

I am having web application for which I have to test load for Monthly Report generation.

Ran thread group for 3 users and analyzing output using View Result Tree Listener, it is displaying '0|error|500||' and under Sampler Result it is displaying 'Response message: OK' for first two samples and for last sample it is displaying response data as 'Response too large to be displayed. Size: 5965092 > Max: 204800, Start of message: etc'

Can anybody tell what will be the issue, why it is displaying error under response data and response message as OK under Sampler Result.

Waiting for your response.

Comment: may you share some snapshots of sampler and result tree data.

Answer (score 0):

As long as JMeter receives something it can parse as HTTP, it won't call that an error.

You're going to want to add Response Assertions to the problem calls. Make sure that it doesn't contain an error depending what the response contains. Documentation can be found [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

When you get these errors after implementing Response Assertions, JMeter will refer to them as '200 errors,' which essentially means it was an error with a 200 response code.